# I need these three stock options to be class level variables, so they are only declared and initialised once

Tags: objective-c, initialization, declaration

I need the three stock options below to be declared and initialised only once. I have got some pseudo-code to achieve it but I'm unsure on how to make it work.

This is declared in the `.m` file of the iOS app and nothing is in the `.h` file .

Pseudo-code is below:

```
// _msftStockPrice _googStockPrice _applStockPrice need to be class level
if(_msftStrockPrice == nil)
googStockPrice = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] monthlyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolMSFT]

if(_appleStrockPrice == nil)
_msftStockPrice = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] monthlyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolMSFT]


if(_msftStrockPrice == nil)
msftStockPrice = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] monthlyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolMSFT]

if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL] == YES) {
   return [_appleStockPrice objectAtIndex:index];
} else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolGOOG] == YES) {
   return [[_googStockPrice objectAtIndex:index];
} else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolMSFT] == YES) {
   return [_msftStockPrice objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with puttin it to `init` or `viewDidLoad` method, then?

Comment: dispatch_once_t much ?

Comment: can you tell me how I would implement it?

Comment: Note the typo near `appleStrockPrice`, where you assign _msftStockPrice, and you use CPDTickerSymbolMSFT three times. Just a little heads up.

Comment: thank you rob, will sort it out!

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare the variables as properties or instance variables, but rather as static variables. Either in the top scope of your .m file, or if the methods above is the only place those variables are accessed, right inside that method. Like so:

```
static NSArray *anArray=nil;
```

static variables will be visible to all instances of your class. Obviously depending on your design (threads) you will need to guard against problems caused by concurrent access.